# Dynamic file content in Terraform

Tags: terraform

I created a file dynamically in terraform. The creation goes into these steps:

- reading the content of some template files
- replacing the variables of the template with variables in terraform
- concatenating all the contents in one single file

The template files are read not following the order I set in the reference terraform `map`.. How can I keep the map order in the for loops?

Here the code:

```
locals {
  template_filenames_with_vars = {
    # key is template filename, value includes variables to replace in the template file
    bbb = {
      var = 1
    }

    aaa = {
      var = 1
    }
  }
}

resource "local_file" "myfile" {
  filename = "file.txt"

  content = <<EOT
${
  join("\n\n", [
    for filename, vars in local.template_filenames_with_vars :
        templatefile("${filename}.txt", vars)
  ])
}
  EOT
}
```

In the example the for loop in the `local_file` content loops in the order `aaa`,`bbb` instead of `bbb`,`aaa`.

Comment: `map` is sorted lexicographically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As previous post and comment said it is not possible to do that with maps, but it is possible to keep order if I use a list of objects:

```
locals {
  template_filenames_with_vars = [
    {
      name = "bbb"
      vars = {
        var = 1
      }
    },
    {
      name = "aaa"
      vars = {
        var = 1
      }
    },
  ]
}

resource "local_file" "myfile" {
  filename = "file.txt"

  content = <<EOT
${
  join("\n\n", [
    for filename in local.template_filenames_with_vars :
        templatefile("${filename.name}.txt", filename.vars)
  ])
}
  EOT
}
```

This keeps the order of the list (`bbb` then `aaa`).

Answer (score 1):

Terraform uses lexical sorting in for loops, see [Element Ordering](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/for#element-ordering), from the docs:

> For sets of strings, Terraform sorts the elements by their value, using lexical sorting.

So it's not possible to keep the map order in this case.